# Is a reference of a shared_ptr still a pointer?

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr

Recently I have a doubt in my work about the reference of a `shared_ptr`. Here is the code.

```
for (const auto & aRef : aVec) {
    THROW_RUNTIME_IFNULLPTR(aRef);
    // do sth
}
```

This is the code of my colleague. In my mind, `aRef` is a reference which can never be null. While I was told that (by `auto &`) `aRef` is still a pointer so it's possible that it's null. The reference is just to not increment the counter. I'm very confused about that.

However, it should be like

```
for (const auto & aRef : aVec) {
    // THROW_RUNTIME_IFNULLPTR(aRef);
    if ( aRef ) {
        aRef->getX();
    }
    // do sth
}
```

Am I wrong about this? I don't think that `aRef` is a pointer.

Comment: In the example provided what is `aVec`? What type?

Comment: Sorry, it's a vector of shared_ptr

Comment: I suppose you could have a reference, to a pointer that is null. (edit: added a comma :>)

Comment: aRef is a reference, so it can never be null.  It can be an alias to a valid pointer that is indeed null...if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to say. It can be a ref to a null pointer. But it can not be null itself. While the pointer here is, if aRef is still a pointer.

Comment: What is the definition of `THROW_RUNTIME_IFNULLPTR`?  Have you tested whether it works with `shared_ptr`?

Comment: regarding: "The reference is just to not increment the counter. I'm very confused about that." A `shared_ptr` is a reference-counted pointer. Every time the `shared_ptr` is copied, the reference count is increased. Every time a copy is destroyed, the count is decreased. When the reference count hits zero, the pointer is `delete`ed. By usiung a reference, the `shared_ptr` is not copied, saving the copy construction and destruction and thus reference count overhead.

Answer (score 8):

> In my mind, `aRef` is a reference which can never be null.

Yes and no. A reference can be everything which the object it refers to can be. If that object is, say, an `int` or a `std::string` or a `std::vector<double>`, then of course it cannot be null (or `nullptr`, to be precise).

If that object, however, is a pointer, for example an `int*`, or a `void*`, or a `MyClass*`, then it can be `nullptr` because the pointer can be `nullptr`.

Now in your case, the object being referred to is a `std::shared_ptr`. It cannot technically be `nullptr`, but it can *represent* `nullptr` by being in a state in which `get()` returns `nullptr`.

> While I was told that (by `auto &`) `aRef` is still a pointer so it's possible that it's null.

More precisely: `aRef` is still a `std::shared_ptr`, so it's possible that it still represents `nullptr`.

Answer (score 5):

`std::shared_ptr` has [`explicit operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool), so in this code

```
if ( aRef )
```

that operator will be called, and it returns true if underlying pointer is not null.

Comment: Just note that it also have [`template< class T >
bool operator==( const shared_ptr<T>& lhs, std::nullptr_t rhs );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp) so `if ( aRef == nullptr )` is also valid.

Answer (score 2):

aRef is a reference. It is an alias for an object.

A pointer is a separate object that perhaps points to another object.

In this case aRef is a reference to an object of type `std::shared_ptr<Something>`.

The code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
auto first = aVec.begin();
auto last = aVec.end();
for( ; first != last ; ++first) {
    std::shared_ptr<Something> const& aRef = *first;
    if (aRef.get() != nullptr) {
        aRef->getX();
    }
    else {
        // handle the case where aRef is not pointing at an object
    }
}
```